# Scala secondary constructor argument visibility

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, case-class

I just noticed that when I have

```
case class Foo(bar : String)(val baz : String)
```

I can't seem to access baz if referencing a Foo in a different package.  Is there anything that can be done about this or do I just need to concede and add an accessor?

Answer (score 1):

This is what the REPL's for!

```
scala> case class Foo(bar: String)(val baz: String)
defined class Foo

scala> val foo1 = Foo("goo")("snoo")
foo1: Foo = Foo(goo)

scala> foo1.baz
res0: String = snoo
```

But be aware that `baz` here does not participate in `copy` `equals`, `hashCode` or `toString` (as you see above), so use additional case class constructor parameter lists with care.

Also, that's not a "secondary constructor."

**Proof**

```
package here {
  case class Foo(bar: String)(val baz: String)
}

package there {
  import here._

  object SnooSnoo {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val foo2 = Foo("flew")("too")

      println(s"foo2=$foo2; foo2.baz=${foo2.baz}")
    }
  }
}

% sbt
> run
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/rschulz/Projects/scribble/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] foo2=Foo(flew); foo2.baz=too
[success] Total time: 5 s, completed Jan 4, 2014 2:07:14 PM
```

Comment: The REPL tells you nothing in this case because in your example all the code is in the same package.  Please read carefully because your answer does not match my question at all. And yes, those arguments are a "secondary" part of the constructor.  If you look at the underlying Java class that is generated they are all part of the constructor.  For example,

    case class Foo(x : Int)(val y : Int)

becomes

    public class Foo implements scala.Product,scala.Serializable {
     ...  
     public Foo(int, int);
     ...
    }

Comment: Package residence has nothing to do with it. And a "secondary constructor" is an entirely separate constructor, defined within the body of the class, not a second argument list to the primary constructor, which is what you illustrated. Naturally the JVM does not have multiple argument lists, whether for constructors or methods, so Scala must compile to the single argument list available in the underlying virtual machine.

Comment: Well, then **why am I seeing an error that the field does not exist**?  Or did you miss that part of my question?  Unless it is a bug in IntelliJ as I suggested.  Everything you wrote is irrelevant to the issue at hand and is pure karma whoring rather than trying to address the **real question**.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it looks like this might just be a bug in the IntelliJ Scala plugin.

Comment: Coorect. IDEA is not faithful to the language as ScalaIDE is.

Comment: Then why did you waste a lot of time telling me things completely irrelevant to the problem and arguing over terminology?

Comment: Aside from the tag, where did you mention IDEA?